ngx-extended-pdf-viewer > page render glitch + pageLabel number
Using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer in Angular and found the following glitch: when I click next page or scroll down, for a split second the page being loaded/rendered appears in the bottow right corner, this also happens when I open the file and the pdf is being loaded, the page appears in a corner for a split second before it appears correctly.
Also I would like to know if there is a way to override the embedded pagination in the pdf so that the pageLabel always matches the actual page number.
I am a beginner so I apreciate any help or tips you can give me!
This is currently my code:
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer
        [src]="doc"
        [language]="'pt-pt'"
        [textLayer]="true"
        [zoom]="zoomSetting"
        [customToolbar]="additionalButtons"
        [filenameForDownload]="docName"
        (pdfLoaded)="pdfLoaded()"
        (pdfLoadingStarts)="pdfLoadingStarts()"
      >
      </ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>

      <ng-template #additionalButtons>
        <div id="toolbarViewer">
          <div id="toolbarViewerLeft">
            <pdf-toggle-sidebar></pdf-toggle-sidebar>
            <div class="toolbarButtonSpacer"></div>
            <pdf-find-button
              [showFindButton]="true"
              [textLayer]="true"
            ></pdf-find-button>
            <pdf-paging-area> </pdf-paging-area>
          </div>
          <div class="zoom-toolbar">
            <pdf-zoom-toolbar></pdf-zoom-toolbar>
          </div>
          <div id="toolbarViewerRight">
            <pdf-hand-tool></pdf-hand-tool>
            <pdf-rotate-page></pdf-rotate-page>
            <pdf-print></pdf-print>
            <pdf-download></pdf-download>
            <button
              type="button"
              (click)="closeEvent.emit()"
              class="btn--toggle-visualizador toolbarButton"
            >
              <layout-icon icon="xmark"></layout-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div> </ng-template
    >

